# Why does Listbox with checkboxes forgets state of items when filtering changes?

Tags: c#, wpf

The users gets a `ListBox` where they check/uncheck the checkboxes of items.

I've added `CollectionViewSource` to allow filtering of the list as it can contain hundreds of items.

If I apply the filter, check/uncheck an item and remove the filter, then it will have "forgotten" the change. So if I checked item 4, when i remove filter Item 4 will be uncheck.
If I do change without filtering, then I'm able to retrieve them.

I have now idea what I'm doing wrong, but my guess is that the displayed collection is a copy of the original source (SourceCollection) and I'm not actually modifying that list.
So when the filter changes, the `CollectionViewSource` creates a new collection base of the source collection.

Here is my code-behind:

```cs
ObservableCollection<Machine> data = new ObservableCollection<Machine>(db.getmachines());
lbItems.ItemsSource = data;
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbItems.ItemsSource);
view.Filter = UserFilter;
```

And my XAML:

```xml
<ListBox Name="lbItems">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just the behavior of `CollectionViewSource`?
What are my options to solve this?
Sorry if I have missed something, just let me know and I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ItemsSource` to the `CollectionView` and not to the underlying data. You should also create the `CollectionView` out of the *original* collection, not the `ItemsSource` property which will not reflect changes made to the original collection.

Change your original

```cs
lbItems.ItemsSource = data;
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbItems.ItemsSource);
view.Filter = UserFilter;
```

into

```cs
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data);
lbItems.ItemsSource = view;
view.Filter = UserFilter;
```

Because you have a binding to `Selected` property, the state will remain unchanged by the `Filter` property you have.

Comment: Works great. It seams so obvious now. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should bind the ICollectionView itself, not the data.

```
// data and view are stored somewhere locally
data = new ObservableCollection<Machine>(db.getmachines());
view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data);
view.Filter = UserFilter;
lbItems.ItemsSource = view;
```

When you need to access your values and see if they were checked or not - use data value. If you need to access only filtered collection, you should cast your view like this:

```
var filteredCollection = view.Cast<Machine>();
```